# z3 cannot prove transitive identity

Tags: z3

I am trying z3 what can it do.
So far so good, but I noticed that z3 fails on very trivial expression:

```
from z3 import *
a = Int("a")
b = Int("b")
c = Int("c")
prove(((a == b) and (b == c)) == ((a == c) and (c == b)))
```

```
$ python p.py
counterexample
[c = 1, b = 0, a = 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `and` is not symbolic-aware. Instead, use `z3`'s `And` method:

```py
from z3 import *
a = Int("a")
b = Int("b")
c = Int("c")
prove(And(a == b, b == c) == (And(a == c, c == b)))
```

This prints:

```
proved
```